# ggplot2 not showing groups

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a tibble that looks like this.

```
d2 <- tibble(Group = c( 'Leadership', 'Leadership', 'Leadership', 'Leadership', 'Parent', 'Parent', 'Parent', 'Parent', 'Parent', 'Parent', 'Staff', 'Staff', 'Staff', 'Staff', 'Staff', 'Staff', 'Teacher', 'Teacher', 'Teacher', 'Teacher', 'Teacher', 'Teacher'),
             Q6.1B = c(2,3,4,NA,1,2,3,4,5,NA,1,2,3,4,5,NA,1,2,3,4,5,NA),
             Count = c(3,12,68,20,21,73,167,314,33,22,4,16,85,231,17,22,2,29,141,410,23,118))
```

When I try to create a grouped bar chart using ggplot2 the chart leaves out some of the group counts. I cannot figure out why.

Here is the code I am using for the ggplot chart.

```
ggplot(d2, aes(x = Q6.1B, y = Count)) + 
    geom_bar(aes(fill = Group, group = Q6.1B), stat="identity", position = 'dodge')
```

The chart I get looks like this:

[image: ggplot2 chart]

There are groups and counts missing, for example, there are 231 staff counts for the 4 group, but they do not show up on the chart. I have tried making the `Group` and `Q6.1B` variables factors, but this doesn't help. I have tried having the group and fill aesthetics be in the ggplot `aes()` instead of the `geom_bar()` `aes`. Nothing has worked for me.

Please help me know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Since `Q6.1B` is already mapped to `x`, you don't need a `group` aesthetic. Simplified: `ggplot(d2, aes(x = Q6.1B, y = Count, fill = Group)) + 
    geom_col(position = 'dodge')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the image below what you're looking for?  Based on your `position = "dodge"` argument and your description, that seemed to be the case.  If not, I'll edit this response with what you're looking for

Edit: How about this one?  If so, the issue was `position = 'dodge'`, as you shouldn't `dodge` the x-axis variable

[image]

```
ggplot(d2, aes(x=Q6.1B, y = Count)) + 
    geom_bar(aes(fill = Group),stat="identity")
```

And welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: It is not exactly what I am looking for. I want the groups to be stacked, but the categories in Q6.1B to be dodged. If that makes sense. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Updated, is that what you're looking for?